# How can I test that the return value from a function in go is a pointer to a type?

Tags: testing, go

I have highlighted in the test case where I expect something should go. Ideally I would like to test that `i` is an instance of `WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE`

main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeType struct {
    thingThatNeedsSetup struct{}
}

func Create() *SomeType {
    return &SomeType{}
}

func main() {
    a := Create()
    fmt.Println(a.thingThatNeedsSetup)
}
```

main_test.go

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestCreate(t *testing.T) {

    i := Create()

    if i != WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE {
        t.Error()
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go is a typed language and so the go compiler guarantees that a function defined as such

```
func Create() *SomeType
```

will always return a value of type `*SomeType` and because of that your example seems rather pointless.

---

If on the other hand you define the function as returning an interface, empty or not, e.g.

```
func Create() interface{}
```

the underlying type of the returned value could be anything that implements that interface, in which case testing for the underlying type may make sense in some cases.

---

You can use the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to test whether two values have equal types. Specifically the function [reflect.TypeOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) which returns a value of type [reflect.Type](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type).

From the docs:

> Type values are comparable, such as with the == operator. Two Type
>   values are equal if they represent identical types.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "reflect"
)

func TestCreate(t *testing.T) {

    i := Create()

    if reflect.TypeOf(i) != reflect.TypeOf(&SomeType{}) {
        t.Error()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that is what I was after. I kept testing for "*SomeType{}" instead of "&SomeType{}"

Answer (score 0):

```
rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr
```